# Adjusting EditTexts when keyboard pops up

Tags: android

I am making a contact book application. `Update Contact` activity is responsible for updating existing contacts' details.

Following image is the interface of `update contact` activity

[image]

when i clicked on any text field, android device keyboard overlapped the text fields. So to fix that issue, i added following line of code to `update activity`in manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

After adding the above line i got the following interface when name field was clicked on

[image]

### Problem

Currently , phone field is displayed over the keyboard only when it is clicked on or when i move the cursor from name field to phone field.

**I want** the phone field to be above the keyboard as well even when name field is clicked on. **How can i achieve this ?**

Following image is what i want when name field is clicked on

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about setting RESIZE instead of PAN? You will be able to keep your EditText above the SoftKeyboard. Try as follows:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

However, instead of doing this at runtime, you can set it in the manifest as an Activity (parent) attribute. This will also be handled in your fragment (child):

```
<activity
    android:name=".NameActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize">
```

Then, as you can see, the `EditText` is above the SoftKeyboard, but from your layout, you have a `TextView` with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` attribute which will overlap the `EditText`:

To prevent this behaviour, just set the ScrollView above the last TextView as follows:
And The XML is Like,

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 

        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:weightSum="1">
---
---
---
        </ScrollView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

And you will get the following result:

[image]

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"` adding this doesn't changes anything. Keyboard still overlaps both text fields

Comment: i am a bit confused, do i have to put scrollview around my parent layout of this activity or the last textview ?

Comment: `from your layout, you have a TextView with android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" attribute` i have no textview that is  aligned at the bottom of the parent layout. I am using `constraint layout` and the `Phone` textview is positioned above the `update contact` button and the button is positioned at the bottom of the parent layout

Comment: `put your all component except parent layout` tried this but phone field only displays over the keyboard when i scroll or when i directly click on the phone field. Can't i adjust both fields above the keyboard automatically when keyboard pops up ?

Comment: Change to ScrollView in this way:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >........... </ScrollView>

Comment: unfortunately it didn't change anything. One thing that i forgot to mention in my question is that all the contacts are shown in a `list view` so using `scrollview` would be a bad idea anyways since `list view` should not be used inside a `scrollview`

Answer (score 0):

Put your two fields in `LinearLayout`. Like the following..

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/ll">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="name"
            android:id="@+id/edit1"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="password"
            android:id="@+id/edit2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Write this tag in `Manifest.xml` inside the activity.

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Comment: tried it but it didn't change anything. Keyboard still overlaps fields.